# How to reduce the number of tokens for this C program

Tags: c, token

I have written a program that takes a number(integer) as an input, and outputs a pattern of 1s and 0s, using for loops. For e.g. when the input is 7, the output is:

```
1 
1 1 
1 0 1 
1 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

The source code is given below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int rows;
    int i,j;
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
        {
            if(i==j)
            {
                printf("1 \n");
            }
            else if(j==0)
            {
                printf("1 ");
            }
            else if (i==rows-1)
            {
                printf("1 ");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("0 ");
            }
       }
    }
   return 0;
}
```

When I compile the codem the number of tokens created is 107. I need to bring down the number tokens to less than 102 (to meet the test requirement).

Any suggestions how can I do it please?

Comment: What do you mean by "token"? What *are* your requirements? What is your assignment? Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: do you mean... number of token in the source code? If that is the case, I am sorry but that is the dumbest assignment ever.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: “Token” is defined in C 2018 6.4 1. The requirement is to have fewer than 102 tokens. The assignment is to write a program that takes an integer numeral as input and produces *n* rows of output with *i* digits in row *i*, 1 ≤ *i* ≤ n, with spaces as shown, with the first and last digit of each row 1, each digit of row *n* 1, and all other digits 0. These are clear from the post, so I do not know why you asked them.

Comment: Is your professor a [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) enthusiast?

Comment: Removing every `{` and `}` except the first and last, respectively, removes 12 tokens, and then you are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

```
int main(void)
{
    int rows;
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
            printf(i == j ? "1 \n" : !j || i == rows - 1 ? "1 " : "0 ");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/3re3beW8W

Or even:

```
int main(void)
{
    int rows;
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++,putchar('\n'))
        for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
            printf(!j || i == rows - 1 || i == j ? "1 " : "0 ");
}
```

or

```
int main(void)
{
    int rows;
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++,putchar('\n'))
        for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
            printf("%d ", !j || i == rows - 1 || i == j);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write the following way

```
include <sdtio.h>

int main( void )
{
    while (1)
    {
        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): " );
        unsigned int n;

        if (scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0) break;

        putchar( '\n' );

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++)
            {
                unsigned int value = i == 0 || i == n - 1 || j == 0 || j == i;
                printf( "%d ", value );
            }
            putchar( '\n' );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 1

1

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 2

1
1 1

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 3

1
1 1
1 1 1

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 4

1
1 1
1 0 1
1 1 1 1

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 5

1
1 1
1 0 1
1 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 6

1
1 1
1 0 1
1 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 1

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 7

1
1 1
1 0 1
1 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```

Or if to reduce the number of tokens then

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    unsigned n = 0;

    scanf( "%u", &n );

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < i + 1; j++)
        {
            unsigned value = i % ( n - 1 ) == 0 || j % i == 0;
            printf( "%d ", value );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just get rid of the braces in your if-else chain? That's 8 tokens, which would get you below your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
  for(j=0;j<=i;j++){
            if(i==j)
                printf("1 \n");
            else if(j==0 || i==row-1)
                printf("1 ");
            else
                printf("0 ");
  }
```

so many tokens can be removed from your code.